# Using Javascript/Jquery to number a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small sample of HTML that looks like this

```html
<ul>
    <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
</ul>
```

I can't edit the HTML itself due to what I'm doing, but I need to basically add a number each time to data-side-to using only js, like so

```html
<ul>
    <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="4" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple code,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul>li").each(function(i,j){
     $(this).attr("data-slide-to",i);
  });
  console.log($("ul").html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
<li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
<li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
<li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
<li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
</ul>
```

I have taken index of li and assigned it to `data-slide-to` attribute of every li.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, it worked mate. I was making an instagram carousel, in case you were wondering.

Comment: :D I wondered specific rather than wander in what's going on :) You're welcome mate!

Comment: *Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.*

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery method **[`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** to loop through all the `li`'s and edit the `data-* attributes` with the index returned from the `each()` method using jQuery **[`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)** method :

```
$('ul>li').each(function(index, value){
    $(this).data('slide-to', index);
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('ul>li').each(function(index, value){
    $(this).data('slide-to', index);
})

//Debug
$('ul>li').each(function(i,v){
    console.log( $(this).data('slide-to') );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
  <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
  <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
  <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
  <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `each` to iterate between `li` and change the value of `data-slide-to` with its `index`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("li").each(function(index){
    $(this).attr("data-slide-to", index)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
<li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
<li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
<li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
<li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes, you are right silly mistake. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('ul li').each(function(i,el)
{
   $(el).attr('data-slide-to',i); // This is your rel value
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

**Core JS**

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
lis.forEach((element,index)=>{
element.setAttribute('data-slide-to',index);
});
console.log(lis);
```

Example:

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
lis.forEach((element,index)=>{
element.setAttribute('data-slide-to',index);
console.log(element);
});
```

```html
<ul>
<li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
<li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
<li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
<li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
<li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, hope this helps you

```js
$('ul>li').each(function(i, obj){
  $(this).attr('data-slide-to',i); 
})

  console.log($("ul").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
  <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
  <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
  <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
  <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" class="appendLi"></li>
</ul>
```